# Package ltablex ruins memoirs "ell" chapter style

Tags: spacing, memoir, ltablex

The package `ltablex` ruins `memoir`'s `ell` chapter style.

So for example this is how I want it to look:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{memoir}

\chapterstyle{ell}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

Adding the package `ltablex` completely ruins it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\chapterstyle{ell}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

I found `\keepXColumns`, which at least partially fixes it, but with that option enabled, the spaces are too large. See:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\keepXColumns
\chapterstyle{ell}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

Is there anything else I can do that will restore the original chapterstyle while keeping the package `ltablex`? (*I need the package to allow `tablularx` tables to be split across several pages*)

Comment: ltablex breaks tabularx, you could keep tabularx as designed and use longtable directly or ltxtable  for multi-page tables.

Comment: Oh my bad. I found `ltxtable` before in other answers but mistyped it as `lxtable`, which didn't exist, so I reverted back to `ltablex`. So thank you. If you'd like to write a quick answer I'll be sure to accept it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Weirdly enough when I change `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}` to `\begin{longtable}{lX}` I get a compilation error: `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate ` (And continuing to use `tabularx` won't make them page break)

Comment: `longtable` doesn't have an X argument (unless you use the special input syntax of ltxtable) so you could use ltxtable or simply use longtable  with `lp{5cm}` or whatever width) or 999 out of 1000 tables with a spec of `lX` would be better set as a list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ltablex` converts all `tabularx` into `longtable` this has the unfortunate effect that they are vertical mode constructs rather than inline line a normal `tabular` or `tabularx`.

You could keep `tabularx` as designed and use `longtable` directly or `ltxtable` for multi-page tables rather than use  `ltablex`.